# bootstrap tab, how to set selected tab on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I'm having some trouble trying to save the current selected tab when the page is reloaded,

I have a bootstrap 3.0 nav nav-tabs setup as my markup, like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="feedtab">
    <li class="active" id="atlasstab"><a href="#atlass" onclick="swapfeeds(1);" data-toggle="tab">Atlass</a></li>
    <li id="aviationtab"><a onclick="swapfeeds(2);" href="#avi" data-toggle="tab">Aviation</a></li>
    <li id="ittab"><a onclick="swapfeeds(3);" href="#proc" data-toggle="tab">IT&S</a></li>
    <li id="processingtab"><a onclick="swapfeeds(4);" href="#it" data-toggle="tab">Plan&Proc</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am storing the lastactive variable into a cookie, the values are correct so it seems my jquery is incorrect, I'm simply trying to set the active tab to the corresponding 'lastactive' variable, IE : 1, 2, 3, 4

I'm aware that tab index starts at zero so i tried to increment the value +!, but still not working,  can someone point out my problem?

this is the javascript im using to try set the active tab:

```
var lastactive = $.cookie("lastactive") != undefined ?  $.cookie("lastactive") : 1;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#feedtab").tabs({active: lastactive + 1 });
});
```

Comment: try alerting lastactive and typeof lastactive in dom ready

Comment: the value of lastactive is correct i tested that, I think it's my jquery being incorrect.

Comment: looks like you are using jquery ui tabs not bootstrap tab

Comment: bootstrap tab  -> http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RK5xe/1/

Comment: Hi can you say action in swapfeeds(3) function on click ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reworked bootstrap example : http://bootply.com/107082 
You have to select the child from the cookie as a jquery object and then call `.tab('show')`.

Comment: hey this works  $(function(){
   $("#feedtab li:eq(1) a").tab('show');
 }); 


but when i change the (1) to my lastactive var it dosnt work, What's wrong?

thanks for the help btw,

Comment: Please follow the approach as present in Arun P Johnny's comment. You are including the variable within the selector expression, instead, you should use an explicit selector as he does.

Comment: i tried to do what he done but it didn't work, your example works but i can't set the value

Comment: thank you!, working !!

 jQuery(function ($) {
 
  var active =  $.cookie("lastactive") || 0;
  
  active -= 1;
  
  $("#feedtab").children().eq(active).find('a').tab('show');

 });